# Running Adobe Flash application on Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: noobs, qemu

I'm working on a project using Raspberry Pi B+ running NOOBS / Raspbian. 
We wish to run a flash application from the equipment manufacturer. 
We used Windows PC / running Windows Vista previously. We install flash application from Adobe (for Chrome and Internet Explorer) and set the manufacturer's flash application to run the from Startup folder.

How do I emulate the above in Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian? I presumed that installing Wine should suffice but Wine is an x86 binary and Raspberry Pi B+ is ARM based...

Is there a way to install Wine or Qemu to run x86 emulation on ARM? Is there a guide / help for doing this?

I had installed Linux Mint 17.2 as dual-boot on my Asus A53SM / K53SM. I installed Wine 1.6.2 "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine". Then I installed the equipment manufacturer's flash application.  Wine insisted to install Mono and Gecko and afterwards the flash application ran correctly.  Now I just need to duplicate this on the Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian...

Since the flash application comes from the equipment manufacturer, short of changing equipment suppliers, I am stuck with this piece of software...

Will appreciate your advise. tq.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Adobe flash version working on the Pi.  Flash itself is deprecated.  Can you not use HTML5?

Comment: Apropos of the conversation: http://adage.com/article/digitalnext/flash-obsolete-time-agencies-adapt/298946/

Answer (score 2):

Adobe flash is proprietary software, and there is no version compiled for ARMv6.  Since it is not open source, that is the end of that.  Running an x86 version through Wine or QEMU, to the extent that it is even possible, will be dreadful.

There is an open source .swf player, [`gnash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/), which is in Raspbian and even looks to use openGL bindings, meaning it might be able to exploit hardware acceleration.  However, it has some limitations and there has not been a new version since 2012.

Comment: I found this on the web but it costs US$19.95 which is more than half-price of the Raspberry Pi itself...
Running Intel x86 applications on ARM-based Mini PCs

With Eltechs ExaGear Desktop you can run Intel x86 application on your ARM-based Mini PC simultaneously with common native applications. ExaGear is a virtual machine that implements virtual x86 Linux container on ARM and allows you to run Intel x86 applications directly on ARM. It is like QEMU but 5 times faster! You can even run Windows applications on your ARM Mini PC if you install Wine...